# Laravel cannot access FormData from an HTTP POST request?

Tags: laravel, http

I'm having trouble getting values from my request when I set the content-type as *multipart/form-data*, but when I set the content-type as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* everything works as expected. The values seem empty.

The request I sent via Postman: 
 [image: A Postman request I sent]

Laravel API snippet:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      ...

public function foo(Request $req){
    echo $req->get('some_key');
}
```

I've tried extracting the values via *$req->get('key_name')*, *$req->key_name* but to no avail. Calling the *$req->all()* method gives me the array with correct content but I have trouble extracting the values from it as well, is there a simpler way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the HTTP response? Are you sending the token in the request?

Comment: @Jason It simply prints out nothing, returning whichever response code I set it to return. It's acting as if the value is empty. No authorization tokens, nothing like that is attached.

Comment: did you find the solution ? i have the same problem, and the accepted answers doesn't help at all... Since i want to POST

Comment: @DarioRega If I recall correctly I defaulted to using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, sorry..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem was with the psotman version i had on linux,i had to upgrade to the 8. beceause i don't know why request were empty in the version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `multipart/form-data`, set the action to `PUT` or `PATCH` and be sure to use the `FormData` object client side:

```
let Data = new FormData();

// using vuejs as an example of appending files.
Data.append( 'your_file', this.$refs.input.files[0], this.$refs.input.files[0].name ); 
Data.append('_method', 'PATCH');

axios.post('/api/foo', Data ).then( Response => { 
   // handle success
});
```

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed :/ I'm using Angular (2) on clientside and I'm sure that my FormData object is properly formatted, confirmed by my Postman requests, I get the same results.

Comment: Have you looked at the network request in the browsers web inspector?

Comment: Yeah, it all seems valid hence I don't think it's an issue with the request I'm sending but the way I try to parse the request on backend.